# Why does Rufus think De Nomolos is dead?

Tags: bill-and-ted

In *Bill and Ted's Bogus Journey*, Rufus presumes that his old teacher,  [De Nomolos](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0224201/) is dead....Why?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Although it's not mentioned canonically, I think it's most likely that he faked his own death so that he could work on his plan to change the past by stealing a time booth and building his (presumably illegal) evil Bill and Ted robots without attracting the attention of the authorities.

Per the [BBC review](http://news.bbc.co.uk/dna/place-lancashire/plain/A4175101) of the film

> "*2691, San Dimas, California. Three years on, and the future might
>   not be looking so great for Bill and Ted. **Chuck De Nomolos (Joss
>   Ackland), presumed dead, isn't happy about his present being built
>   upon the legacy of two fools and he wants to change all that.** In the
>   future, our Rufus (George Carlin) is teaching the 'physics of
>   acoustical reverberation' at the Bill and Ted University with special
>   guest speakers thanks to the time travelling phone booth.*"